# 2.5-inch border running across top of browser window

Tags: css

For my site, I would like a 2.5-inch border, colored #DE2A00, running across the top of the browser window, regardless of browser width.  I would like it flush to the top of the browser window.

How can I do this?

Comment: As long as you are okay with an approximation, 2.5 inches is impossible to specify precisely due to different monitor resolutions, pixel pitches, etc.

Comment: 2.5 _inch_? That's enormously wide.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
body {
   border-top: 2.5in solid #DE2A00;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
.topBar {
    height: 2.5in;
    background-color: #DE2A00;
}

<div class='topBar'></div>
```